# stuck with the vigenere.c

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, vigenere

> I am stuck in this example. Whenever I put the keyword 'bacon' I get the wrong answer.
>     Any idea why this is happening? I can't find the bug and I have tried a lot.
>     Can you please help me?

When I run this:  `./vigenere bacon`  and input the text `Meet me at the park at eleven am` the answer should be `Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz`, but instead I get `Negh ne og tjs qaty bt syfvgb bm`

> Update: I made some changes as suggested by the comments but still having the same problem.

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check if it has only two values
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // check that every letter of keyword is alphabetic
    char *keyword = argv[1];
    int keylen = strlen(keyword);
    for (int i = 0, n = keylen; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(keyword[i]))
        { 
            printf("alphabetic keyword only!!!\n");
            return 1; 
        }

       if(isalpha(keyword[i]))
       {
           // if a letter of keyword is uppercase
           if (isupper(keyword[i]))
           { 
               keyword[i] = keyword[i] - 'A';
           } 

           // if a letter of keyword is lowercase
           if (islower(keyword[i]))
           {
               keyword[i] = keyword[i] - 'a';   
           } 
       }  
    } 

    char *text = GetString();
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {    

        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            // if plaintext letter uppercase then...
            if (isupper(text[i]))
            {
                text[i] = ((text[i] - 'A') + (keyword[i % keylen])) % 26 + 'A';
                printf("%c",text[i]);

                                           // ^^^^^^ ----> repeat the pattern
            }

            // if plaintext letter lowercase then ...
            if (islower(text[i]))
            {
                text[i] = ((text[i] - 'a') + (keyword[i % keylen])) % 26 + 'a';
                printf("%c",text[i]);

            }
        }

        // if no letters in plaintext then ...
        if (!isalpha(text[i]))
        { 
            text[i] = text[i];
            printf("%c",text[i]);
        }  
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What does "wrong answer" mean?  What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: when i enter arguments **./vigenere bacon** and text **Meet me at the park at eleven am** the answer should be **Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz** instead i get **Nffu nf bu uif qbsl bu fmfwfo bn**

Comment: `keyword[i % strlen(keyword)]` : You may `strlen` does not operate normally after you convert to a number `keyword`. (e.g.keyword[i] = keyword[i](when 'a') - 'a' == 0)

Comment: So i should declare the **strlen(keyword)** before the loop? or should i ovoid using **int cypher** and istead use **text[i]**?

Comment: that should be saved in advance the length of the keyword.

Comment: `me` -> `zf` is It is not considered that the spaces are counted.

Comment: I changed that i still get the wrong answer

Comment: `int keylen = strlen(keyword);` : `keyword` is too late than from being converted. put on after `char *keyword = argv[1];`.

Comment: yeah ...it is driving me crazy... i am going to hit my head into the wall right now

Comment: _I get Negh ne og tjs qaty bt syfvgb bm_ : `i` of the index is counted including spaces. You need to provide a different variable that counts the valid character to get a result like what you want.

Comment: YesSSS ...finaly i have to be so much more careful...Can you make it an answer so i can vote  you? Thanks man

Comment: One more question: Why doesn't the computer ignore **spaces** since i declared **if (isalpha(text[i]))**?

Comment: A: `for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)`

Comment: For disgnostic purposes, try using a very simple plaintext like, `aaa ... aaa`.  That will show more of the pattern of what your code is actually doing, as opposed to what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So as @BLUEPIXY suggested I had to use a different variable in order to get the right answer:

```
   `char *text = GetString();
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {    

    if (isalpha(text[i]))
    {
       // if plaintext letter uppercase
       if (isupper(text[i]))
       {
            text[i]= ((text[i] - 'A') + (keyword[k % keylen])) % 26 + 'A';
            printf("%c",text[i]);

                                        //^^^^^ ----> repeat the keyword pattern   
       }

            // if plaintext letter lowercase
       if (islower(text[i]))
        {
            text[i] = ((text[i] - 'a') + (keyword[k % keylen])) % 26 + 'a';
            printf("%c",text[i]);

        }
        k++;
     }`
```